# Solr document name returning too many results?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.6 to index content and it works well.

Now when i search with content name "TheSource_August_8th_2014.pdf", it should return only one document with same name, instead it is returning too many (>1000) results which are irrelevant to query.

Can anybody help?

Comment: can it be an issue with tokenization or with underscore?

Comment: Does your query include the "" signs around the query term?

Comment: No, i am not using double quotes around query term.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only get exact matches, use a field with a type of `StrField`. A `StrField` doesn't have any Analyzers or Tokenizers attached to it, which means that a hit will be a hit - only if it's exactly the same.

If you still want to do some processing (such as lowercasing the name), you can use a `TextField` with a `KeywordTokenizer` attached to it, as the `KeywordTokenizer` leaves the token stream intact. You can then add a lowercasing filter to make the contents lowercase for easier searching.